# Exact vs. conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding definitions.

What's the difference between something being exact and being conservative? I understand both involve proving that a potential function $f$ exists such that
$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=M\hat{i}+N\hat{j}+P\hat{k}=\frac{∂f}{∂x}\hat{i}+\frac{∂f}{∂y}\hat{j}+\frac{∂f}{∂z}\hat{k}$$
but I'm not understanding what makes something *exact* as opposed to *conservative*, or vice versa.

Is it just that differential equations can be exact and vector fields can be conservative, or is there more to it?

EDIT: Fixed a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, your last paragraph is right. It's just terminology coming from two different points in history. They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Exactness is a property of differential forms, like $M \,\mathrm{d}x + N \,\mathrm{d}y + P \,\mathrm{d}z$. In particular, if a differential form $\alpha$ is exact, then the equation $\alpha= 0$ is also said to be exact.
- Conservativeness is a property of vector fields, like $(M,N,P)$.

Comment: What exactly does "exactness" mean?

Answer (score -2):

They are [particular case and general case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10574/how-do-i-make-the-conceptual-transition-from-multivariable-calculus-to-differenti):

[Differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) are a generalization of scalar/vector fields.

[Exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) is a generalization of gradient/divergence/curl.

${\bf F} = \nabla f$ is a particular case of $\lambda =d\omega$.